# Evaluating react component string and embedding it into another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I have a react component in a string as such:

```js
"
function App() {
    return (
        <h1>h1</h1>
    )

};
"
```

the question is how can I evaluate the string and embed this react component in another react component?

Comment: Could you describe the use case under what circumstances do we need to achieve such thing . And how would you achieve making this string in first place

Answer (score 0):

Considering we will somehow get the react comp in a string we can evaluate the string and expect it to return a valid react DOM .

In an ideal case when we have a simple functional react component we can do something like this

```js
let Str = function App() { return ('Hello')};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{Str()}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

Now I will just wrap the function in a string ,
There are two way I can get my function back

1. We have to tweak the string a bit , add a variable to the string as if the function is being assigned to the variable. Evaluate the string which will store the string into a variable so that we can execute the variable as and when we want . (eval is dangerous and your linters will warn you not to use unless you are very sure what are you upto)

   "x = function App() { return ('Hello')};"

now if we have a variable in scope we can have our function back in the string .

```js
let Str = "Xstr = function App() { return ('Hello String')}";
let Xstr;
function App() {
  //eslint-disable-next-line
  eval(Str);
  console.log(Xstr);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>
        <Xstr />
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

2. Tweak the function to a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), Evaluate it to get your output

   "(function App() { return ('Hello IIFE')})()"

```js
let Str = "(function App() { return ('Hello IIFE')})()";
function App() {
  const comp = eval(Str);
  console.log(comp)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{comp}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"><div>
```

I could not think of another way other then eval and considering this is not a ideal way to deal with react functions it should be fine to use it .

Comment: this wont work if there are html tags in the component's return statement